# react native init fails macOS / cdn.jsdelivr.net/

Tags: react-native, macos, cocoapods, jsdelivr

I have been working on react-native for over 2 years with no major issues on windows.
I am struggling to make it work on my new Mac. init fails.

```
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
```

[Codegen] Found rncore
Fetching podspec for boost from ../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec
Fetching podspec for glog from ../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec
Fetching podspec for hermes-engine from ../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-engine/hermes-engine.podspec
[Hermes] Using the release tarball from Maven Central
[!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 2 error(s):
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/9/9/libevent/2.1.11/libevent.podspec.json
Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/9/9/libevent/2.1.12/libevent.podspec.json
Response: SSL connect error

I discovered that this site https://cdn.jsdelivr.net has blocked access to my country.

React Native Version: 0.72.3
OS: macOS 13.4.1
Node version: 18.16.1
Yarn version: 1.22.19
Ruby version: 2.7.5
CocoaPods version: 1.12.1
Xcode version: 14.3.1/14E300c

1. Is there a way to use another setup that does not need files from cdn.jsdelivr.net? (May be an older version of react-native or cocoa...)
2. Is there another server for the required react-native cocoapods thet does not restrict users ?

Thanks,

Comment: Any chance there was a jsdelivr outage like there is now? https://status.jsdelivr.com/

Comment: Ooh check this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11939